Can anyone critique my hardware design plan?
I am designing a custom circuit. The circuit should verify that a signal is high for ten seconds by outputting a high signal once the time has been reached. My plan is:

Send a clock signal through a frequency divider. The output clock will be 1 Hz
Feed this 1 Hz clock to a 4 bit up counter. It should increment the counter once per second.
The counter is enabled by the high signal I am checking.
When/if binary 10 is in the counter register, output 1 by inverting and ANDing the counter bits together
Use this output to set a SR latch and reset the counter.

Are there any flaws in this approach that I am not seeing and is there a better way to accomplish this?

Besides the issues mentioned in the two answers provided, if it's not that critical to your circuit, the signal you're checking is solid high and not varying (again, if above certain threshold and unimportant to your design) and you merely want to get a signal after it lasts 10 seconds, it should be OK. Without more details about your circuit and its specific needs, it is hard to tell for sure.

Is this for a professional product or just some one time project? As a software dude I wouldn't even consider this but just use a small MCU with good enough clock resolution. Will improve BoM costs a lot compared to a forest of 74HC logic, but you do need to program it.

You could improve your current method by not dividing the clock at all, and implementing a counter that counts up to 10s / clock period. As noted you'll need to include a reset if the signal falls low. Depending on your Clock frequency you'll start to approach an error that may be acceptable, but you might start to need a large counter. There may be a good midpoint where you divide the clock down to get good resolution, but not too massive a counter.

Yes there are flaws. It does not fill the specs of the input signal needing to be high for 10 seconds.
It only checks of the input signal is high when a 1 Hz clock tick happens for 10 clocks. At other times, the input signal can do anything, and a low input simply does not advance the counter.
So it's possible that a 9 second pulse counts up to 9 and a hour later if the input is simply high for one clock edge, the counter hits 10 with very short input.
And I forgot to mention that it requires the input to be high for at least 10 seconds minimum, as 9.999999 seconds is one microsecond less than 10s. So in practive it will be longer than 10 seconds, and rounding up the clock pulses makes 11 seconds.

Could this not be fixed by resetting the counter every time the signal goes low?

Yes, but another problem is the +/-1 second ambiguity in the timing relationship between the input signal and the 1 Hz clock.  This can be solved by resetting the entire divide chain along with the 4-bit counter.  Now, when the input signal releases the Reset, there is a full second before the counter gets a clock pulse, +/- the period of the high-speed clock driving the divide chain.

Think about what happens if the signal is high for 0.999 seconds - unless you want the output go high after the input has been high for an uninterrupted 10 seconds and even then it's much better to use a higher resolution counter and logic to catch the 10 second point. Or unsurprisingly this is something that can be done on a tiny microcontroller.
